# Syntax error in array program

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I am trying to write worksheet data range from one place to other using array approach with a view to try array manipulation later. This program works fine.

```
  Sub Array2Range5()

    Dim Directory As Variant
    Directory = Range("A30:D39").Value2

    For i = LBound(Directory, 1) To UBound(Directory, 1)
    For j = LBound(Directory, 2) To UBound(Directory, 2)
        Worksheets("List").Range(Worksheets("List").Cells(i + 1, j + 1), Worksheets("List").Cells(i + 1, j + 1)) = Directory(i, j)
    Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

The following program for same purpose gives run time error ‘9’.Subscript out of range in the following code portion.

```
           Worksheets("List").Range(Worksheets("List").Cells(i + 1, j + 1), Worksheets("List").Cells(i + 1, j + 1)) = Directory(i, j)
```

I am not able to correct it and the program is as follows.

```
 Sub Array2Range6()

    Dim Directory As Variant
    Directory = Range("A30:D39").Value2

    For i = 0 To UBound(Directory, 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(Directory, 2)
        Worksheets("List").Range(Worksheets("List").Cells(i + 1, j + 1), Worksheets("List").Cells(i + 1, j + 1)) = Directory(i, j)
    Next j
    Next i
  End Sub
```

My query is whether these lines are wrong in syntax. If so what should be the correct syntax on similar lines

```
    For i = 0 To UBound(Directory, 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(Directory, 2)
```

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumping values from a worksheet range into an array always results in a 1-based 2-D array not a zero-based 1-D or 2-D array.

Proof this with the following:

```
Dim Directory As Variant
Directory = Range("A30:D39").Value2

debug.print LBound(Directory, 1) & " to " & UBound(Directory, 1)
debug.print LBound(Directory, 2) & " to " & UBound(Directory, 2)
```

The first works because you are using the LBound; the latter fails because you are specifying the LBound to be zero when it is actually 1.

Personally, I always use LBound for the lower boundary regardless of whether the array is a zero-based 1-D array, a one-based 1-D array (using [Option Base 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-base-statement) directive) or a one-based 2-D array.